# Emacs and. sh (or. bash)?

Tags: bash, emacs

I've tried finding an Emacs specific answer to this one, so apologies if it is repetitive. Simple question. I know that from the point of view of the interpreter it doesn't matter if you write a bash script with or without the .sh or. bash suffix, but does using one of either of these change the way in which Emacs treats the file when editing it? I've been playing around with some bash scripts in Emacs, and I've half answered my question. But I'm brand new to bash, so a lot is still unclear.

Thanks :)

wds

PS. I've asked this question in my programming class but to no avail.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html. *» Emacs checks whether the file's contents begin with ‘#!’ [...] Therefore, Emacs tries to use the interpreter name to choose a mode. For instance, a file that begins with ‘#!/usr/bin/perl’ is opened in Perl mode.«*

Answer (score 4):

Various ways emacs can determine the `major-mode` and shell type

1. look at the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env bash` line
2. Match the file extension to a major mode according to your `auto-mode-alist` configuration.  You can set `bash` as the default shell to use by configuring `sh-alias-alist`, eg. `(cl-pushnew '(sh . bash) sh-alias-alist :test #'equal)` in your shell config file.
3. Using a local variable, eg. as the first line of a script: `# -*- sh; sh-shell: bash; -*-` to tell emacs the major mode is `sh` and to use the `bash` shell.
4. Set the major mode interactively with <kbd>M-x sh-mode</kbd> and set the type of shell by setting the local `sh-shell` variable or using the the `sh-script` function `sh-set-shell`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. We've been told in class that we should use the .sh extension, but not why. I know it doesn't make a difference regarding whether the script runs, hence this thread :)

Comment: That goes against normal advice for executable scripts.  Typically you only add the .sh extension for sourced scripts.  That way if you change the implementation of an executable, for example rewrite it in C, it still has the same name.

Comment: My lecturer doesn't do a great job at explaining bash concepts in general. His explanation of a while loop is 'ok, a while loop is like a for loop but this bit is different. Moving on...', not bothering to chfck whether we even understand the subtlites of the way for loops are implemented in bash. I can program in C, so I get the logic. But the syntax confuses the hell out of me, so it'd be nice if he explained things a little better :)

Comment: I would recommend looking at how the scripts are structured in a well written open source library, eg. a GNU project like emacs, or read their style guidelines for these sorts of details.  There is also some guidelines maintained on github, https://github.com/progrium/bashstyle, although I think some of the stuff they recommend is a bit over the top

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow that up. Much appreciated.