# Shell script mode automatically at each emacs start

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, startup

Each time when I edit bash script I type a command `M-x shell-script-mode`. And then I get nice shell code higlighting. How to get it automatically each time I start emacs so I do not have to type the command. When I added `(shell-script-mode)` to `init.el` it did not help.

Comment: emacs should start `sh-mode` automatically based on a number of [tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55230845/emacs-and-sh-or-bash/55231109#55231109)

Comment: Please provide a recipe for reproducing the problem, so we can understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the default major mode to be whatever you want by adding

```
(setq-default major-mode 'shell-script-mode)
```

to your init file. That will ensure that any newly created buffer will be in `shell-script-mode` unless its mode is specified otherwise (e.g. through `auto-mode-alist`). Whether it's a good idea or not, I don't know: I probably would not want that to be my default setting - but to each her/his own.

Answer (score 1):

One of the simplest ways to have Emacs set the desired *mode* for a buffer editing a file is to include a special comment in the first line of that file, e.g. for a shell script your first line might be:

```
# -*-sh-*-
```

For scripts it is also common, or and often even required, to have an interpreter file comment on the very first line of the file, which of course would preclude having an Emacs mode comment, so Emacs also looks for interpreter file comments and associates those with a major mode, so the first line of your shell script might be:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

There are a number of other ways to tell Emacs how to set the buffer mode when visiting a file.  See, for example, [Emacs Manual: Choosing File Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Choosing-Modes.html)

Comment: The thing is that until you save that buffer and revert the buffer from the saved file, its mode is still `fundamental-mode` or whatever the default major mode is. I guess the OP is trying to avoid that.